# Fibonacci identity $F_{n+1}^2 - (F_{n+1}F_n) - F_n^2 = (-1)^n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, fibonacci-numbers

I am trying to prove

Let $F_n$ be the $n$th Fibonacci number. Then $F_{n+1}^2 - F_{n+1}F_n - F_n^2 = (-1)^n$

I am not sure where to start with this.

Comment: Have you tried writing this out for some small cases (e.g. $n = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5$)?

Comment: You meant start with a base case?

Comment: Yes, it can eventually work into that. But if you have no idea where to start, why not try proving it for some small values of $n$ that you can work with by hand?

Comment: So I get what a base case is. E.g pick a starting value. But I cannot visualize how to input even just one in the above sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Observe the truthfulness of the statement for $n=0$: $$1^2 +1\cdot0 -0^2 =1=(-1)^0.$$

We can then show it by induction for all $n$. That is, being true for $k+1$ is implied by the assumption that it's true for $k$:

$$ \begin{align} (F_{k+2})^2 - F_{k+2}F_{k+1} - F_{k+1}^2 &= (F_{k+1} + F_{k})^2 -F_{k+1}(F_{k+1} + F_k)  -(F_{k+1})^2 \\ &= -(F_{k+1})^2 + F_{k+1} F_k + (F_k)^2 \\ &= -(-1)^k = (-1)^{k+1}. \end{align} $$

Comment: @user1787331: Is there something I should clarify?